# Integrating Socket.io 1.0 client with c# program

Tags: c#, sockets, socket.io-1.0

I'm new to sockets and I've been trying to integrate a Socket.io 1.0 client in my C# program without much success.

I'm using [SocketIoClientDotNet](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet) to do the job, which is the only option I've found which supports socket.io 1.0 (for instance [SocketIO4Net.Client](https://socketio4net.codeplex.com/) only supports 0.9, unfortunately). The program was initially targeting .NET framework 4.0 which I have to change for compatibility with [SocketIoClientDotNet](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet) which apparently supports .Net 3.5 and 4.5.

A snippet of my code:

```
using SteamKit2;
using SteamTrade;
using SteamTrade.TradeWebAPI;
using SteamTrade.TradeOffer;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client;
using Quobject.EngineIoClientDotNet.Client.Transports;
using Quobject.EngineIoClientDotNet.ComponentEmitter;
using Quobject.EngineIoClientDotNet.Modules;
using Quobject.EngineIoClientDotNet.Parser;
using Socket = Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client.Socket;

namespace Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {
        public override void fooBar()
        {
            // just to test, didn't go any further because of errors
            var socket = IO.Socket("http://localhost");
            socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
            {
                socket.Emit("hi");
                socket.On("hi", (data) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(data);
                    socket.Disconnect();
                });
            });

            // more code...
        }

        // more code...
    }
}
```

This is where the problems begin:

[SocketIoClientDotNet](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet) adds a reference to `System.Threading.Tasks.NET35`.

»» Targeting .Net Framework 4.0 or 4.5 without removing the reference causes the error:

```
Error   17  The type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>' exists in both 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll' and 'c:\MyApp\trunk\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Unofficial.3.1\lib\net35\System.Threading.Tasks.NET35.dll'
```

»» Changing the target framework to 3.5 causes other dependencies to break with `Error  396 The type or namespace name 'FooBar' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
, so I can't do that as well.

»» Removing the reference to `System.Threading.Tasks.NET35` causes a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` Exception by `Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client.IO`

Essentially I'm stuck here and in need of guidance. Any help and sugestion on how to get Socket.io 1.0 working here will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have 25 `using` statements? I see that you've trimmed some code out for brevity but that statement count in a single file makes me suspect that there's very little separation of concerns going on. This code smell may also make your issue more difficult to resolve.

Comment: To help you figure out your issue: I would create a separate, standalone project which should do the very simplest thing with socket.io. Basically a Hello World for socket.io. Doing this will help you isolate the problem and identify a solution.

Comment: Apparently the problem was caused because SocketIoClientDotNet was installed when targeting .Net 4.0, which wrongly required System.Threading.Tasks.NET35. Targeting the .Net 4.5 and only then reinstalling SocketIoClientDotNet solved the issue.

Comment: Glad you solved this issue. You should write it up as an answer to make this post useful to people. You can accept your own answer. Also, make a comment with @PaulSasik and I will upvote it. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the problem was caused because SocketIoClientDotNet was installed when targeting .Net 4.0, which wrongly required System.Threading.Tasks.NET35. Targeting the .Net 4.5 and only then reinstalling SocketIoClientDotNet solved the issue.

Comment: [SocketIoClientDotNet](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet) is supporting .net 4.0 in release [0.9.10](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet/releases/tag/0.9.10).